# authorize.net dpm credit card expiration date select field

Tags: payment-gateway

I am creating a form to submit to Authorize.net using the DPM.  I believe the credit card expiration date must be formatted as yyyy/dd in a single variable.

I would like to use two fields on my html form: one drop-down select field for the month and one for the date.  How can I combine the two html form fields into one variable so that it is submitted to Authorize.net as one correctly formatted variable on submit?

I suspect this could be done with javascript, however, it must work every time, even if javascript is disabled.

Thanks for any help or alternate suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to change the accepted answer, but I would recommend that you do so.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want it to work without JavaScript then you will need an extra step to process the form submission and then display the final information back to the user. Then they can submit it to Authnet to use DPM.

Comment: ok, this makes perfect sense.  However, if I do this processing and then display the information back to the user for submission to Authorize.net, will I have to meet PCI requirements sense the credit card info is being processed on my server?

Comment: As I understand it, this would defeat the point of using DPM for the reason you suggest.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I handled it.

Users with javascript enabled see separate drop-downs for the month and year, as you suggested. Users without javascript see a text input field with the proper date format indicated.

You definitely do not want to post the form contents back to the origin server, since that defeats the point of using the [Direct Post Method](http://www.authorize.net/support/DirectPost_guide.pdf).

Here's the basic code using JQuery.

```
<form id="cart-form" action="...">
...

Expiration Date:
<div id="exp_date_wrap">
    <input name="x_exp_date" type="text" /> (format: mm/yy)
</div>

<select name="x_cc_month" id="x_cc_month" style="display:none">
    <option value="">-- month --</option>
    ...
</select>

<select name="x_cc_year" id="x_cc_year" style="display:none">
    <option value="">-- year --</option>
    ...
</select>

<script>
  $('#exp_date_wrap').hide();
  $('#x_cc_month, #x_cc_year').show();

  $('#cart-form').submit(function() {
    $('#x_exp_date').val(
      $('#x_cc_month :selected').val() + '/' +
      $('#x_cc_year :selected').val()
    );
  });
</script>

</form>
```

Comment: I would avoid using the name attribute on the x_cc_month and x_cc_year fields (i.e. don't give them a name). That way they won't get submitted to the Authorize.Net DPM entry point. Just the IDs will be enough. If they do get submitted, then they will end up being treated as custom fields, and be posted back to your site to the callback (relay) page, which brings PCI questions back to the forefront. But otherwise, a great solution.